# What would happen if I deflect a Ghast's fireball and it hits a pigman?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Would the pigman be aggressive at me?

Comment: Have you tried anything to confirm this theory?

Comment: I'm simply interested. I don't want to try - today is not a day to be killed by pigmen...

Comment: I think it will make the pigmen aggressive to you, my partner thinks otherwise because you didn't **fire** the fireball.

Comment: -1 for reluctance of testing your own theory.

Comment: That's fair enough - but I was thinking it wouldn't be easy to try it. I was hoping someone would know from experience / game code / other source.

Comment: -1 for not even checking the wiki article on pigmen

Comment: @MrLemon I did skim read it - evidently not thoroughly enough. I assumed this would not be listed there as it is quite a rare occurrence.

Comment: @Tim Never assume without doing your research.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I created a Cheat Enabled world in Survival Mode, went Creative and went to the Nether.

There I spawned a few Ghasts and some Pigmen using Spawn Eggs and gave myself a few Splash Potions of Healing II to keep myself alive.

At one point, the Ghast hit a Pigman directly, the Pigman did nothing.

After hitting a fireballs for a few minutes, I managed to hit a Pigman with a deflected fireball, all surrounding Pigmen immediately became aggressive and started attacking me.

So yes, deflecting a Ghast's fireball and hitting Pigman with it causes them to become aggressive.

I tested this in Minecraft 1.8.1, but it should work in any version starting Alpha 1.2.0.

Also, it so on the wiki and from sever other sources such as:

https://sites.google.com/site/minecraftinfo20/neutral-mobs/zombie-pigman#TOC-Behavior
Zombie Pigmen roam the Nether in packs of 4 - 10 and make grunting and squealing noises, avoiding cliffs and Ghasts. Attacking one Zombie Pigman will cause the entire group to turn hostile and swarm the player. **Hitting Zombie Pigmen with deflected Ghast fireballs also provokes them.**

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Talk:Zombie_Pigman#Wrong_information_regarding_Ghast_deflection
" Pushing a Zombie Pigman off a cliff, as well as hitting them with a deflected Ghast fireball or otherwise causing environmental damage to them will not cause response." I think this is wrong, as **I was just attacked after definitely only reflecting a Ghast fireball into one by accident**.

Answer (score 4):

###The pigmen will be hostile

This is covered on the wiki article on [Zombie Pigmen](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie_Pigman#Hostility), under Hostility

> - Pushing a zombie pigman off a cliff or otherwise causing environmental damage to them will not make them hostile.

> - However, damaging zombie pigmen with TNT ignited with flint and steel or flaming arrows will make them hostile, because these count as player-induced damage.

- Similarly, **damaging zombie pigmen with a redirected ghast fireball will make them hostile**.

However, killing a zombie pigman in one hit does not cause the other pigmen to be hostile. On hard difficulty, a Ghast fireball does a maximum of 25 damage, which is enough to one-hot a pigman with its 20 hp and 2 armor (25*(1-2*0.04)=23>20). The article does not state whether this would affect the hostility of the other pigmen.